# flex 3 data grid: hide value if == 0 and show checkbox on Booleans

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, itemrenderer

I have a data grid. How can I hide a value of a column if it's "0" ? Do I have to use item renderers? How? Is there an easier way?

Second thing, if I have a boolean column whose values are actually the strings "true" and "false" how can I render it as a non editable check box?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question: you can do it with `labelFunction` property of datagridcolumn.

```
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="fieldValue" editable="false"
  labelFunction="hideZero">
private function hideZero(item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String
{
  if(item.fieldValue == 0)
    return "";
  return item.fieldValue;
}
```

second question: use a drop in item renderer.

```
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="dValue" editable="false">
  <mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
      <mx:CheckBox selected="{data.dValue == 'true'}"/>
    </mx:Component>
  </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

replace dValue with appropriate dataField.

Answer (score 1):

This is an improved version which works without naming explicitly the field you are working on.

```
private function hideZero(item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String
{
  if(item[column.dataField] == 0)
    return '';
  return item[column.dataField];
}
```